# How Practical iOS Push notification

Tags: ios

My understanding is that iOS Push notification have limitation:

- Do not guarantee delivery.
- And there might be delay in receving these notification.

Considering these limitation, I was thinking that application such as WhatsApp messenger will not be practical. But it seems iOS Push notification is not bad. 
Hence, My question is:

- In practice, how reliable iOS Push notification , for example, 99%?
- Usually, how long notification delivery it takes , for example, < 1
  minute?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using the extended push notification format, your server knows when a notification was unable to be sent, and you can handle that case accordinly.

Comment: Thanks ... how often non-delivery happen? also, what about deplay?

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is reliable, in my experience (I have written 5 apps using push over the past 4 years) they get delivered > 99% of the time and within just a several seconds.
Note that there are serious issues though with background push in iOS8. But if you are just using foreground push its reliable though not 100% guaranteed of course.